# What is meant by normalized projection operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

What is meant by normalized projection operator? What is its physical meaning in quantum mechanics? I am pretty confused regarding the physical interpretation of both projection operator and normalized projection operator.

Comment: It's sort of like casting a shadow (that's why they named it a "projection" operator).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose we have arbitrary vectors $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ that are not necessarily aligned with one another. We can determine the *component* of $|\beta\rangle$ that lies along the direction of $|\alpha\rangle$ by defining an operator
$$
\hat{P}=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|
$$
which we call the **projection operator**. Note that $\hat{P}$ is considered normalized if 
$$\sum\hat{P}=\sum|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|=1$$
which is then the ***normalized* projection operator**.

We can then use $\hat{P}$ as,
$$
\hat{P}|\beta\rangle=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle=\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle|\alpha\rangle
$$
If, however, $\hat{P}$ is not normalized, then we must use
$$
\hat{P}|\beta\rangle=\frac{\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle|\alpha\rangle}{\sum|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|}
$$

---

As an aside, let's look at $\hat{P}^2$:
$$
\hat{P}^2=\left(|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|\right)\left(|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|\right)=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|=\hat{P}
$$
where we used the fact that $\langle\alpha|\alpha\rangle=1$. This property is called [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) and is a consequence of the fact that once you've projected a vector onto another vector, projecting it a second time gives you the same projection.

Using this property on a vector $|a\rangle$,
$$
\hat{P}^2|a\rangle=\hat{P}|a\rangle
\\
\left(\hat{P}^2-\hat{P}\right)|a\rangle=0
\\
\left(p^2-p\right)|a\rangle=0
$$
Where $p$ is the eigenvalue $\hat{P}$. The solution is either $p=0$ or $p=1$.

The eigenvectors for the appropriate eigenvalues must satisfy
$$
\hat{P}|a\rangle=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|a\rangle=|a\rangle\quad p=1
\\
\hat{P}|a\rangle=|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|a\rangle=0\qquad p=0
$$
For $p=1$, the appropriate eigenvector is $A|\alpha\rangle$ for constant $A$ (i.e., any vector parallel to $|\alpha\rangle$ is an eigenvector). For $p=0$, the appropriate eigenvector is 0 (i.e., it is orthogonal).

Comment: I don't think the eigenvalue part makes much sense, since even if $|\beta\rangle$ is not an eigenvector of $\hat P$, we always have $(\hat{P}^2-\hat P)|\beta\rangle=0$, since $\hat{P}^2=\hat P$.

Comment: @Adam: The key is not to look at the $\hat{P}^2-\hat{P}$ part but to look at $\hat{P}|\beta\rangle$. This will either be $\mathbb 1|\beta\rangle$ or $\mathbb 0|\beta\rangle$ because it is either parallel or orthogonal to basis $|\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: I think you have a problem of notation then. You said $|\beta\rangle$ is not necessarily orthogonal to $|\alpha\rangle$, so you have in general $0\leq\langle\alpha|\beta\rangle\leq 1$, and therefore $\hat P|\beta\rangle=a|\alpha\rangle$ with $0\leq a\leq 1$ (that's the definition of a projector).

Comment: @Adam: The aside is separate from the initial answer (before the thin solid line). I'll clean it up in a few minutes to assert that more clearly.

Comment: @Adam: Aside cleaned up. Let me know if this is still confusing.

Comment: You are still assuming that $|a\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\hat P$, which is not necessarily the case for a general vector. There are plenty of $|a\rangle$ such that $\hat P |a\rangle= c|\alpha\rangle$ with $0\leq c\leq1$. Btw, I don't think your fourth equation make much sense too, since you have $\sum |\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|$ in the numerator, which is certainly not a normalization.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, I am assuming $|a\rangle$ is an eigenvector, I state as much. I also state that there is some constant $A$ which seems to be the same as your $c$, so I am not sure what your complaint is. Lastly, I do not see any summation of $|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha|$ in the numerator of equation 4.

Comment: It's just that I don't think that this "eigenvector" thing has much interest. And I meant denominator in the equation 4.