# What is the standard definition of "projector", "projection" and "projection operator"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, definition, linear-algebra

What is the precise meaning of "projector", "projection" and "projection operator"? I always thougth those two terms are synonyms, but I have seen both used in a quantum optics paper where the former is not the same as the latter. There the projector was defined as $(I_S|0)$ and the projection operator as
$\begin{pmatrix}
I_S & 0\\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
with $I_S$ being the identity for a subspace $S$. So the first is a block-vector and the second a block-matrix? I have never seen such a distinction before and could not find any material about that online.

Comment: Despite the somewhat loosely wording zoo there is "Idempotence" as a common defining property: $P^2=P$. If a notion of orthogonality/a scalar product is available, then "Orthogonal project..." (idempotent & self-adjoint) get important. You may consult ["FA" by D. Werner](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/werner99/fabuch/funkana4.html), in particular §IV.6 and §V.3 (referring to the 3rd edition of the book).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108142/25301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, people will use all of these words interchangeably, to mean what your source calls a "projection operator". As for what your source means, note that

- a linear transformation is a linear map $T: V \to W$ for vector spaces $V$, $W$
- a linear operator is a linear map $T: V \to V$ for a vector space $V$

We are always working with linear transformations, but sometimes one may specify a transformation is an operator to emphasize that the input and output space are the same.

A projection can be thought of in either way. Suppose that the projection maps vectors in $V$ to a subspace $W$ of $V$. Then we can think of it as a linear transformation $T: V \to W$ where $W$ is regarded as a vector space of its own (what your source calls a projector, represented by a non-square matrix), or we can think of it as a linear operator $T: V \to V$ where the image happens to be $W \subset V$ (which your source calls a projection operator). Making such a distinction might be useful if you want to be very explicit about what the spaces are, but it's not standard.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same thing. In quantum mechanics, one usually defines a projection operator as $$\hat{P} = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$$
This operator then acts on quantum states (vectors) $|\Psi\rangle$ as
$$\hat{P}|\Psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Psi\rangle = \langle\psi|\Psi\rangle|\psi\rangle$$

This is exactly the same as the projector you defined in matrix form, since we can think of $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ as the diagonal components of a matrix. For example, if $|\Psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle$, we would find that the projector projects out a particular state $$\hat{P}|\Psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle$$

In matrix form this would be exactly the same as what you defined, since now
\begin{equation}\label{key}
\hat{P} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},~~~~~ |\Psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\ 
\beta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

And now 
$$\hat{P}|\Psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\ 
\beta
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is it standard to express all $|\psi\rangle$ in a state space in terms of the orthonormal basis vectors $|\psi\rangle$'s?